# WordPress - Using Variable For Site Link?

Tags: wordpress

I have the following link on my WordPress website:

```
<a href="http://example.com/privacy/">Privacy</a>
```

I'm planning to clone this site and would like to have a way so that the domain part of this link will automatically change when I deploy it to a different site.  The name of the web page will remain the same.

For example, if I deploy it to MySite2, it would be:

```
<a href="http://example2.com/privacy/">Privacy</a>
```

Is there Wordpress variable that I can use?  I suspect I need something like:

```
<a href="[WordPress Site Var]/privacy/">Privacy</a>
```

Does anyone happen to have the exact link that I would use?

Comment: Try <?php bloginfo('url');?>/privacy

Answer (score 3):

Seems you want a function that gets your URL dynamically. Something like

`<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/privacy/">Privacy<\a>`

Find more about this function at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url

Answer (score 0):

**If you want a dynamic URL that is in a shortcode** - that's what I thnk you mean with the brackets around `[WordPress Site Var]` that will go in page/post content - than you're talking about a shortcode. *You can't execute PHP in post/page content without a plugin; and a shortcode is much better for portability, anyway.*

Create a shortcode for the whole `<a href...` link, not just the URL, i.e.:

```
    function shortcode_for_a_url() {
    ob_start();?>

    <a href="https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo">
    Function Reference/bloginfo « WordPress Codex
    </a>

    <?php return ob_get_clean();
    }
    add_shortcode('my_url_shortcode', 'shortcode_for_a_url');
```

in your theme functions.php file.

Use `[my_url_shortcode]` in post/page content.

That shortcode will output the html `<a href="https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo">Function Reference/bloginfo « WordPress Codex</a>`

You can also throw that function into a simple plugin to make the shortcode portable and outside of the theme:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Shortcodes
Description: My URL Shortcodes
Version: 1.0
License: GPL
Author: Blah Blah
Author URI: http://example.com
*/


 function shortcode_for_a_url() {  blah blah blah...
```

**If you need a PHP function to go in a theme file**, then see [Function Reference/bloginfo « WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) for all the standard Wordpress parameters, i.e. using

`<?php bloginfo( $show ); ?>`

and the variable:

```
admin_email          = admin@example.com
atom_url             = http://www.example.com/home/feed/atom
charset              = UTF-8
comments_atom_url    = http://www.example.com/home/comments/feed/atom
comments_rss2_url    = http://www.example.com/home/comments/feed
description          = Just another WordPress blog
home                 = http://www.example.com/home (DEPRECATED! use url option instead)
html_type            = text/html
language             = en-US
name                 = Testpilot
pingback_url         = http://www.example.com/home/wp/xmlrpc.php
rdf_url              = http://www.example.com/home/feed/rdf
rss2_url             = http://www.example.com/home/feed
rss_url              = http://www.example.com/home/feed/rss
siteurl              = http://www.example.com/home (DEPRECATED! use url option instead)
stylesheet_directory = http://www.example.com/home/wp/wp-content/themes/largo
stylesheet_url       = http://www.example.com/home/wp/wp-content/themes/largo/style.css
template_directory   = http://www.example.com/home/wp/wp-content/themes/largo
template_url         = http://www.example.com/home/wp/wp-content/themes/largo
text_direction       = ltr
url                  = http://www.example.com/home
version              = 4.2.1
wpurl                = http://www.example.com/home/wp
```